# tikzpicture with xbar interval and nodes near coords is missing an interval label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm trying to create an `xbar interval` chart with `nodes near coords`. This works with some shifting etc., but the interval label is missing for the topmost value (or the value is extra, depending on how you see it). How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
cvar & percent \\
0.0 & 168 \\
0.005 & 188 \\
0.01 & 159 \\
0.015 & 87 \\
0.02 & 49 \\
0.025 & 0 \\
}\data

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
    \begin{axis}[
            yticklabel style={
               /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, /tikz/.cd
            },
            scaled y ticks=false,
            width=7cm,
            axis lines=left,
            tick label style={font=\small},
            xbar interval,
            grid=none,
            ymax=.03,
            xmax=250,
            ytick=data,
            yticklabel interval boundaries,
            y tick label style={font=\tiny},
            xmajorgrids,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={align=right,xshift=5pt,yshift=5pt,font=\tiny},
        ]
        \addplot[] table[y=cvar,x=percent]{\data};
    \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

I'd like that zero up top to be gone, or an interval label to its left.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This removes the 0.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
cvar & percent \\
0.0 & 168 \\
0.005 & 188 \\
0.01 & 159 \\
0.015 & 87 \\
0.02 & 49 \\
0.025 & 0 \\
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            yticklabel style={
               /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, /tikz/.cd
            },
            scaled y ticks=false,
            width=7cm,
            axis lines=left,
            tick label style={font=\small},
            xbar interval,
            grid=none,
            ymax=.03,
            xmax=250,
            %ytick=data, %<-removed
            yticklabel interval boundaries,
            y tick label style={font=\tiny},
            xmajorgrids,
            visualization depends on={\thisrow{percent} \as \myvalue},
            nodes near coords=\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{\myvalue}
            \ifnum\itest>0
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\myvalue}
            \fi,
            every node near coord/.append style={align=left,anchor=south west,font=\tiny},
        ]
        \addplot[] table[y=cvar,x=percent]{\data};
    \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]